# Dashboard (BI) in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

how I can visualize a SharePoint data  list as a graph or dashboard in SharePoint online (office 365).

Comment: How adept are you with JavaScript? Or do you need a no code solution?

Comment: with no code i want a solution to do that .

Comment: Research into Excel Services, if you have this available to you in your SharePoint Online.

Comment: where i can found this ; another thing that i want visualize the graph in my site SharePoint not in excel . thank you for your answers

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sharepoint+online+dashboard+excel+services :)